# Updating/Displaying Multiple Dataframes with ipywidgets

Tags: python, user-interface, ipywidgets

I have two dataframes in which I'm trying to create a new column in each and have a user enter data in that column for a particular index label of that df.

I have a dropdown widget to select the df (from a separate dict, "dfs") and a dropdown widget to select the appropriate index value, along with a text box widget to enter data into a newly created column.

I'm running into trouble in a couple places.

1. when you use add_more_button_widget to add additional dropdowns/text boxes to define more data, it will only update this in the df of the very first row (i.e. if I have df1 selected in the first row and df2 selected in the second row, both changes will be made in df1
2. the clear_output() doesn't seem to be working the way I intend. Basically it only clears the selected index row, but I would like it to clear the entire new_column before writing the user input data into selected rows

Any tips would be super appreciated!

These are my initial set of widgets

```
# Create the first dropdown widget
df_widget = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=list(dfs.keys()),
    value=list(dfs.keys())[0],
    description='Dataframe:',
)

# Create the second dropdown widget
index_widget = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=dfs[df_widget.value].index.tolist(),
    value=dfs[df_widget.value].index.tolist()[0],
    description='Select Row:',
)

# Create the text box widget
text_box_widget = widgets.Text(
    value='',
    placeholder='Enter value',
    description='Enter Data:',
)

# create output widget for displaying dataframe
output = widgets.Output()

# Define a function that updates the content of index based on what we select for df_widget
def update_index(*args):
    index_widget.options = dfs[df_widget.value].index.tolist()

df_widget.observe(update_index)


# Create the button widget that displays both dataframes
button_widget = widgets.Button(
    description='Display Dataframe',
)
```

**This block below is where I believe I start to have the issues
**

```
# function to update dataframe with new data
def update_dataframe(b):
    # loop through all hbox layouts in vbox layout
    for hbox in vbox.children:
        # get selected row from dropdown
        row_index = hbox.children[1].value

        # get data from input widget
        user_input = hbox.children[2].value

        # add new column to dataframe
        dfs[df_widget.value].loc[row_index, 'new_column'] = user_input

    # clear output area
    with output:
        clear_output()

    # display updated dataframe
    with output:
        display(dfs['df1'].fillna(''))
        display(dfs['df2'].fillna(''))

# attach button click event to update_dataframe function
button_widget.on_click(update_dataframe)


# Create the "Add More" button widget
add_more_button_widget = widgets.Button(
    description='Add More',
)


# function to add more rows of data
def add_more_rows(b):
    # Create the first dropdown widget
    df_widget_new = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=list(dfs.keys()),
        value=list(dfs.keys())[0],
        description='Dataframe:',
        
    )

    # Create the second dropdown widget
    index_widget_new = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=dfs[df_widget.value].index.tolist(),
        value=dfs[df_widget.value].index.tolist()[0],
        description='Select Row:',
    )

    # Create the text box widget
    text_box_widget_new = widgets.Text(
        value='',
        placeholder='Enter value',
        description='Enter Data:',
    )

    # create hbox layout for new row of data entry widgets
    hbox_new = widgets.HBox([df_widget_new, index_widget_new, text_box_widget_new])

    # add new row of data entry widgets to vbox layout
    vbox.children += (hbox_new,)

# attach button click event to add_more_rows function
add_more_button_widget.on_click(add_more_rows)
```

This block just to display the whole thing

```
# create hbox layout for initial row of data entry widgets
hbox = widgets.HBox([df_widget, index_widget, text_box_widget])

# create vbox layout for all rows of data entry widgets
vbox = widgets.VBox([hbox])


# display widgets and output area
widgets.VBox([vbox, add_more_button_widget, button_widget, output])
```